# unable to locate pacakge popcorn time through terminal during installation

Tags: command-line, package-management, locate

Hi am a 64bit Linux user.

I've been trying to install Popcorn time using the terminal, after I type
`sudo apt-get install popcorn-time-linux64` and that’s how it was saved when I downloaded the package from their website, it gives me:

```
E: Unable to locate package popcorn-time
```

Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

popcorn-time is not available in default ubuntu repositories however you can use webupd ppa and install it from there

> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/popcorntime
>
> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get install popcorn-time

Comment: thank you.. i tried that but it tells me to check the ppa name or formate is correct

Comment: Seems like the repository has been taken down due to dmca, it is available on offcial site but you will have to extract and compile it to make it work. https://popcorntime.io/